# White space at the end of my HTML / CSS site

Tags: html, css

So I just started making the site and there is a lot of white space at the bottom of my site...

I've been removing div but than on Inspect Element shows that the white space is because of `<ul></ul>` when I removed that tag it showed it is because of `<body>`

They say add `margin: 0; padding:0 html,body { height:100%;}` but nothing worked.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoR';
    src: url("/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoM';
    src: url("/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoB';
    src: url("/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoLi';
    src: url("/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
  }

  html,body {height:100%;}

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin:0;
}


.navigacija a{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'RobotoR', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
}
.navigacija a:hover {
    color:#202020;
    font-weight: bold;
}
 .navigacija a:visited{
    color: #202020;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 10em;
    right: 5em;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo{
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    left: 5.1em;
    top: -2.5em;
}
.kontakttelmail {
    position: relative;
    top: -11.5em;
    left: 83.9em;
    font-family: 'RobotoLi', sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 1em;
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.button {
    background-color: white; 
    border: none;
    color: #00A651;  
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 85em;
    left: 57.5em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'RobotoB', sans-serif;
  }
  .zelenakrivina{
      position: relative;
      width: 90%;
      right: -15em;
      bottom: 8em;
      padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
  }
  .auto{
    position: relative;
    width: 49%;
    right: -24.5em;
    bottom: 44em;
    padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
  }
  .zelenisvg ul li{
      position: relative;
      bottom: 95em;
      left: 80em;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style-type: none;
}
.zelenisvg {
    
}
  .Renault{
      position: relative;
      top: -0em;
      right: 0.1em;
      color: white;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'RobotoM', sans-serif;
      padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
  }
  .Megane{
    position: relative;
    top: -1.3em;
    right: 1.1em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'RobotoB', sans-serif;
}
.lajna{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 124em;
        left: 63.7em;
        width: 11%; 
}
.a30e{
    position: relative;
    top: -1.58em;
    right: 0.7em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'RobotoB', sans-serif;
}
.nadan{
    position: relative;
    top: -11em;
    right: -0.6em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'RobotoR', sans-serif;
}
.sivitext{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 22em;
    font-family: 'RobotoB', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    left: 2.5em;
    color: #212121;
}
.zelenitext{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 23.2em;
    font-family: 'RobotoB', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    left: 2.5em;
    color: #00A651;
}
.ispodnaslova{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 61.2em;
    font-family: 'RobotoR', sans-serif;
    font-size: 23.8px;
    left: 6.3em;
    color: #585858;
}
.scroll{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 110.9em;
    /* left: 15em; */
    width: 8%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.strelica{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 115.9em;
    /* left: 15em; */
    width: 4.2%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>S T A R T - Rent-a-Car</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
    type = "text/css"
    href = "style.css" />
</head>
<header>
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        <nav>
                <ul class="navigacija" id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Početna</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sva vozila</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">O nama</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontkat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <p class="kontakttelmail">email@gmail.com  +382-68-222-333</p>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="zelenisvg">
      <img src="images/Path 1.svg" alt="zelenakrivina" class="zelenakrivina">
      <img src="images/renault-migan-e1541771231987.svg" alt="renault" class="auto">
      <p class="sivitext">Uz naša vozila ste</p>
      <p class="zelenitext"> korak bliže cilju!</p>
      <p class="ispodnaslova">Na vaš poziv dovodimo željeno<br>
        vozilo na vašu adresu!</p>
        <ul>
         <li><p class="Renault">Renault</p></li>   
        <li><p class="Megane">Megane</p></li>
        <li><p class="a30e">30€</p></li>
        <li><p class="nadan">/na dan</p></li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="location.href= 'Svavozila.html'" class="button">Rezervisi odmah!</button>
    <img src="/images/Line 1.png" alt="linija" class="lajna">
<img src="images/Path 9.svg" alt="scroll" class="scroll">
<img src="/images/Path 2.png" alt="strelica" class="strelica">
    
</div>

</body>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML. You should have 1 `<html>` tag in the root of your document, and within that, one `<head>` followed by one `<body>`. You can't have headers and footers outside of the body.

Comment: use some HTML validator tool to check if what you are coding is valid: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input , because right now, it is completely invalid

Comment: I see where the confusion comes from. `Body` does not actually stand for the "body" of the site (aka the contents between header and footer), but it is infact most of your site's visible structure. You have to include both `header` and `footer` tags inside the `body` for it to become valid. Also, as @Ivar pointed out you're missing the closing `html` tag at the end of the document.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I did all that you suggested to do, I fixed my code (at least what that validator said to fix) but I still have that white space at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like someone said in the comments section:

```
</body>
<footer>

</footer>
```

You can't have the footer outside the body element.

Take a look at this link:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure/

You'll understand how the HTML markup should look like :)

EDIT:
Your HTML seems to look better now but your CSS is breaking everything up. Why do you apply the `position: relative` to every single CSS rule you create ? Look https://jsfiddle.net/t23mkxz4/
I've removed `position: relative` and everything looks much better. Please - do some research on how to use the `position: relative` property :)
take a look at this link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
it's a great source of knowledge and examples. Good luch mate !

Comment: If you have any more questions - please let me know :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for letting me know how I should code and I fixed that and went on validator for html and fixed those errors, but still there is a blank space on the bottom of the site.. I don't know can  update the code somehow if not I can send the pastebin of the code?

Comment: Yea - send me the pastebin. I'll try to help once I'm back home. Make sure that I'll be able to reproduce the error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T3GYNa8S- html
https://pastebin.com/i9fRt7g6 - css 
Thanks man

Comment: "This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff"

Comment: You've sent me 2 different HTML files. Which one of them is the right one one how does the issue look like ?

Comment: Thanks man, I think I get why I had a lot of blank space I saw some tutorial about positioning things in css and saw position relative and top / bottom / left / right and I probably closed the page and started making a website xD